# How to enable CORS using canvas running from a Phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, canvas

I am using KineticJS to add images to a canvas element, and when any image is added I cannot get the dataUrl of the rendered canvas due to CORS security issues.

The fixes I found on StackOverflow suggest passing an allow-access-origin header on the "server", but since this is a local application running on the iPad there is no server so it is considered local.

Is there a workaround for enabling the dataUrl feature so I can save a "tainted" canvas while running locally on an iPad?

The code I'm using to grab the URL is as follows:

```
$(document).on("tap", "#share-menu-button", function() {
    stage.toDataURL({
        callback:function(dataUrl) {
            alert(dataUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: if local here means file:// it's still considered a different origin, and you will need a local server as a minimum to serve both page and images from.

Comment: If it's local, can you load the page that contains the canvas element from `file://` as well? Not sure if that would work, but it might... E.g. creating an `<iframe>` with `src` pointing to `file://some/path/somefile.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do canvas.toDataURL to images with "file:///" schemes on iOS in Cordova, and getting various errors, including: "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

The solution that worked for me involved two steps:

1. Add to the <platform name="ios"> section of config.xml:

   <preference name="scheme" value="app" />

   <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />

as documented here:
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html

2. Update the filename returned in the Success callback from navigator.camera.getPicture(), from the "file:///" scheme to your new "app://" scheme using:

   imageFileName = window.WkWebView.convertFilePath( imageFileName )

as (kind of) documented here:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/issues/622#issuecomment-659357799